# ErrorDocument is not working for 401 response

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect to a custom error page using a redirect in .htaccess. Please check the site jobslanda.com. The line `ErrorDocument 401 401.php` is not working. I am using the following configuration in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([\w.,]+)/([\w.,]+)/([\w.,]+)/([\w.,]+)/([\w.,]+)/([\w.,]+)$ job.php?j=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([\w.,]+)/([0-9]+)$ sameIndustryJobs.php?i=$1&c=$2&p=$3
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([\w',]+)/([0-9]+)$ sameCatagoryJobs.php?c=$1&s=$3&p=$4
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([\w.,]+)/([0-9]+)$ sameCityJobs.php?c=$1&cn=$4&p=$5
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([\w.,]+)/([0-9]+)$ sameQualificationJobs.php?q=$1&cn=$5&p=$6

ErrorDocument 401 401.php

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
```

Comment: "Is not working" tells us very little. What happens? When asking for help, always state what you expect to happen and what actually happens, including any error messages. Also, questions should be self-contained so that helpers don't have to spend time hunting things down, so that the issue is preserved (if and when you fix the issue on your site, the issue is lost) and so that the question is searchable. Remember, SO questions aren't just for you, they're for everyone that has the same issue.

Comment: It looks like you would benefit from reading SO related documentation, such as the FAQs and Jon Skeet's ["Writing the Perfect Question"](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints).

Answer (score 0):

Is it because you did not spell **".htaccess"** correctly? (And your Apache installation is not picking up the file?)

Comment: Thanks for your replay. But the htacess file is working well. Please check http://jobslanda.com. Only problem with ErrorDocument 401 401.php.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you have the 401.php file located on your web server?  Typically the `ErrorDocument` directive should begin with a `/` and reference a page relative to your web root.

Reference:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#errordocument

You don't appear to have a page at:
`http://jobslanda.com/401.php`

Oddly, that's returning a `302` redirect to a page called `404.php`.